# Cannot cancel repeating alarm

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I am using targetSdkVersion 24. I set up an alarm like this:

```
    alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("REQUEST_CODE", CHEW_REQ_CODE);
    intent.putExtra("CHEW_TEXT", chewText);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, CHEW_REQ_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + interval, interval, pIntent);
```

where interval is 15 x 60 x 1000 = 15 min. This alarm is set in a check box in the preferences. On a HTC One running API 23 the alarm goes off as expected. However, when I cancel this alarm by unchecking the preference, the alarm keeps going off. This is my cancel code:

```
    if (alarmMgr != null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra("REQUEST_CODE", CHEW_REQ_CODE);
        intent.putExtra("CHEW_TEXT", chewText);
        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, CHEW_REQ_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        alarmMgr.cancel(pIntent);
    }
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure that code is called when you uncheck the preference item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Blehi, I found that the code was not called. The part was this:

```
    if (alarmMgr != null) {
        alarmMgr.cancel(chewIntent);

    }
```

AlarmReceived is implemented as Singleton, while the AlarmManager is instantiated in my setAlarm. So alarmMgr was null when the alarm was canceled.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to hold on to the original PendingIntent object you use in `alarmMgr.setRepeating(...)` instead of creating a new one.  Something like this should help;

```
PendingIntent startAlarm(Context context){
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("REQUEST_CODE", CHEW_REQ_CODE);
    intent.putExtra("CHEW_TEXT", chewText);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, CHEW_REQ_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + interval, interval, pIntent);
    return pIntent;
}

void stopAlarm(Context context, PendingIntent pIntent) {
    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    if (alarmMgr!= null) {
        alarmMgr.cancel(pIntent);
    }
}
```

Then usage in your class would be something like the following (here I used onPause and onResume of an Activity):

```
PendingIntent alarmIntent;

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    alarmIntent = startAlarm(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (alarmIntent != null) {
        stopAlarm(this, alarmIntent);
        alarmIntent = null;
    }
}
```

HTHs!!!